# How to show "if operator in for operator" in block algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, if-statement, block

For Example:

```
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++){
   if (i % 3 == 0){
      cout << i;
   }
}
```

How to show this code in code-block algortihms?

Comment: Perhaps I'm just not familiar with the terminology here, but what do you mean by "code-block algorithms?"

Comment: It's not ringing any bells for me either. Perhaps "flow chart"?